# Should I use the past tense or present tense?

Tags: word-choice, tenses

I am struggling to choose the correct tense for this question:

What were the names of the sons of Mahatma Gandhi?

OR

What are the names of the sons of Mahatma Ghandi?

His sons have passed away so I would naturally opt for 'were', but they are still his sons so 'are' seems more appropriate. Is this correct? Thank you.

Comment: For people in general, we only apply "are" to the living, because in an important sense they "are" no more. Just like we don't say George Washington *is* the first president of the USA, though no president preceded him, because George Washington *isn't*.

Comment: Also related: [Simple present or past in a series of past events?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/113346/8019)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use "were" due to the fact that the sons have since passed on. Generally speaking, "are" is associated with the present.

Answer (score 0):

Any **change of context**, including one of tense, will be seen as **jarring** by the reader if not motivated.

Do you really have **any reasons to change here to the present, to show that their names have not changed through history (obvious anyway)**?

You don't. Use the first.